# Attribute Error for all my functions in Pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I was using Spotify API extract data to create a web app and display it using Streamlit and I wanted to test it. However, as I tested it using Pytest it gave me an attribute error for all my functions (e.g. `AttributeError: module 'project' has no attribute 'get_artists_albums'`). The following is a section of my code showing the functions not being recognized.

```
import requests
import streamlit as st
import base64
import time
from streamlit_image_select import image_select

# gets the artists id from spotidy search
def get_artist(input, token):

    #request artists information
    response = requests.get(
        SPOTIFY_GET_ARTISTS_ID + input + "&type=artist&limit=4", #uses user search and the type is limited to artist while the amount is limited to 4
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bearer {token}"
        },
    )

    json_format = response.json()


    return_id = {}
    artists_img = []
    artists = []

    #for loop that puts artists images, and artists names into lists and
    #creates a dict with the key being the artists name and the image being
    for c in range(len(json_format["artists"]["items"])):

        #if there is an image for the artist then the process goes normally
        if json_format["artists"]["items"][c]["images"]:
            artists_img.append(json_format["artists"]["items"][c]["images"][0]["url"])
            artists.append(json_format["artists"]["items"][c]["name"])
            return_id[json_format["artists"]["items"][c]["images"][0]["url"]] = json_format["artists"]["items"][c]["id"]
        #if there is no image for the artist then a "NO IMAGE" image is inserted instead
        else:
            artists_img.append("https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ffffff/000000&text=NO+IMAGE")
            artists.append(json_format["artists"]["items"][c]["name"])
            return_id["https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ffffff/000000&text=NO+IMAGE"] = json_format["artists"]["items"][c]["id"]

    if artists_img:

    #Each artist image and name are displayed for the user to choose for
        img = image_select("Choose your artist", artists_img, captions = artists)

    # return the artist that the user chose
        #print(f" : {return_id[img]}")
        return return_id[img]
    else:
        st.write("No results")
        return ''



# get that artists albums
def get_artists_albums(token, ID):

    #request artists albums
    response = requests.get(
        SPOTIFY_GET_ARTISTS_ALBUMS_URL + ID + "/albums?include_groups=album", # uses the artist ID and only get albums
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bearer {token}"
        },
    )
    #print(response)
    # if the rate limit is exceeded retry-after statement applied
    if response.status_code == 429:
        # Rate limit exceeded, wait for the specified duration
        retry_after = int(response.headers.get('Retry-After', 100000))  # Default to 100000 seconds
        print(f"Rate limit exceeded. Waiting for {retry_after} seconds.")
        time.sleep(retry_after)
        # Retry the API request
        return get_artists_albums(token, ID)

    if response.status_code == 400:
        st.error('Sorry! Refresh something went wrong')
        return {}
    else:
        #change to json format
        json_format = response.json()
        #print(json_format)

        #get amount of albums and create list to store ids
        album_list_length = len(json_format.get("items", {}))
        album_ids = {}

        #extract album ids from the json
        if album_list_length != 0:
            for i in range(album_list_length):
                album_ids[json_format["items"][i]["name"]] = json_format["items"][i]["id"]
                # print(json_format["items"][0])

        #return dict with key being artist name and value artist id
        #print(album_ids)
        return album_ids



# get artists albums
def get_album_tracks(token, album):

    #request albums tracks
    response = requests.get(
        SPOTIFY_GET_ALBUMS_TRACKS_URL + f"{album}/tracks?limit=40",
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bearer {token}"
        },
    )


    #print(json_format)
    if response.status_code == 429:
        # Rate limit exceeded, wait for the specified duration
        retry_after = int(response.headers.get('Retry-After', 100000))  # Default to 10 seconds
        print(f"Rate limit exceeded. Waiting for {retry_after} seconds.")
        for remaining_seconds in range(retry_after, 0, -1):
            print(f"Remaining seconds: {remaining_seconds}", end='\r')
            time.sleep(1)
        # Retry the API request
        return get_album_tracks(token, album)

    if response.status_code == 400:
        st.error('Sorry! Refresh something went wrong')
        return []
    else:
        #change to json format
        json_format = response.json()
        #get amount of albums and create list to store ids
        track_list_length = len(json_format["items"])
        track_ids = []

        #extract album tracks ids from json
        if track_list_length != 0 and track_list_length >= 5:
            for i in range(track_list_length):
                track_ids.append(json_format["items"][i]["id"])
                #track_ids.append(json_format["items"][i]["id"])
                #print(track_ids)
            #print(track_ids)
            return track_ids
        else:
            return []
        # return list of ids
```

These following is the test file for it:

```
import pytest
import project


access_token = project.get_access_token()

def test_get_artist():
    #try valid artist
    assert project.get_artist("Willow",access_token) == "3rWZHrfrsPBxVy692yAIxF"
    #try gibberish search
    assert project.get_artist("shshhshs",access_token ) == ""



def test_get_artists_albums():
    #try normal artist
    assert project.get_artists_albums(access_token,"3rWZHrfrsPBxVy692yAIxF" ) == {'<COPINGMECHANISM>': '0oMXn0MNLNyvB4iJPZXOuV', 'lately I feel EVERYTHING': '1dg0gmrCaEbENVXpPIvi1m', 'THE ANXIETY': '2kZyqn4Cmr78D74K9TcO4K', 'WILLOW': '4B2pV5Zds6478QOqA8yqdj', 'The 1st': '0YrdQQiUYjNmLPs0SI53qy', 'ARDIPITHECUS': '0oFPwpDPEsrIYoeGZLFQUv'}
    #try artist with zero albums expected to return empty dict
    assert project.get_artists_albums(access_token,"3pau9bvYGSbZqjCmY1UK8y") == {}
    #try invalid artist id
    assert project.get_artists_albums(access_token,"5mZLaYqN0ZkjxfeUUmiuq" ) == {}
    

def test_albums_tracks():
    # normal request
    assert project.get_album_tracks(access_token,"0oMXn0MNLNyvB4iJPZXOuV") == ['5qMq8ITRVuTwqd2pDL0gff', '0LCHO5qNN5fEncfAIcjtAH', '2OdRGWLkvSccWOrYFlbIFF', '1WCPaQ7zMEMwWbpuTrhM9S', '7fH0VGK95wUN25QN5lmP4c', '2A4pnMV0s7tE00CPiImhLO', '1v3d3KsoHgmiWEI6vFyJ0t', '4OvlUfaJKuZ9aJVAJWmwyE', '0FqkI0vR3Z28v6GSudbKXj', '6ddFCqaAgHeoGaNkaLJ0At', '5w1cL1HG1xJWeBhcUIc1Jw']
    # mac demarcos long album will return only first 40 tracks
    assert project.get_album_tracks(access_token,"70hX7IYqmUGV97OXs2v848" ) == ['5ftED3IYts5K7gChGOUuHG', '5DQnFVwslZtmU0hDgf3wor', '4Qoyylq2zm3eBpENMQ59Xu', '1t6JzKUfGZjoYDZIzkYqSm', '4JwtnmvP4TPi1C1CRwJgiI', '04E2ASMFE8dt2guBV8i0Bd', '6tD7ltNWepcIn7sGAq0wwv', '6MSK4PQrBTaM3j51TrzLM0', '6hMO5tPpQoa2rmOQBhmlx1', '4tX3cJZoR3alDFrdZMOGtV', '4hVsTyDdaliuwc00bYrtsf', '34FNLYnBXyBExIO340XLqx', '46ZE35M0hnO1CeGrXPx1Nu', '3wlFGJ5SJV4o0yYx4o4OlV', '19p6twffpQSqYLBF8MPij6', '6SLCuCK5QExoqqhKexAWuB', '4MCID4Fy8zpZzCRJWiSqXB', '1kBFQhNypLgTw9ouqmIxOO', '4F8zPyKsPM5DTsk2uqqQ8p', '419VY1AgmoxegGhyOhPCuH', '3N8hso233NNlPYJwdSUXNo', '2dSves9EaHZHT9s8eOCcK3', '2ql2ZhziOm1dW2uGI8DLq7', '6unIOeUaYgBZ8TgCWNGDPX', '6L3kq3nfseC0GL1NRPGJaC', '4NDKUI4vFOccDpVTpKRv64', '0khZxbRqdcSPU1GiIgQzkI', '0xCMl9Oymkg8amUwZokFRo', '0fg1xiFdr3DFBYwUzDe5mZ', '5EaxMO1IVSlxo6MV3qKhVV', '3s5HsxVX6spY0ycibLJx2q', '3Vde5vALhDIebbDGGeC5ai', '1BD42GcRTk4kHqdElk8jbx', '7F4HlP13JC2lz2o3xenkpU', '0j4fiXOAYaQNdLb9hDfu8b', '3oUn55qKRZ1JFzfQNbJjS1', '72pFsXc9gE7XKUR9KaN1Ji', '7BxRB28QvwQIsRJpB35Eu2', '3wvW8GIpS8Y95nCt2Wjt5t', '1x7joV0bl6uPwnO3jpfqeb']
    # albums with less than 5 tracks will return empty string
    assert project.get_album_tracks(access_token,"0Hs3BomCdwIWRhgT57x22T" ) == []
    #what happens when invalid id inserted
    assert project.get_album_tracks(access_token,"0Hs3BomCdwIWRhgT57x22" ) == []
```

I get the same error for all the functions, my functions are not being recognized by my testing file. It is as if these functions do not exist, even though the file I want to test is imported, what is the problem, How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide the solutions i found suitable for my problem in the answers, feel free to add on them with your own answers. I wanted to share my knowledge for this as I did not find the answer easily.

There are three solutions that I found to be the most probable in this case:

1. The first being the fastest to check which is deleting the `__init__.py` file if you have one in the same directory as the test, especially if your python is version 3.3+ as it is unnecessary for versions greater than 3.3. This is because `__init__.py` files affect test discovery.
2. Make sure that you are accessing your functions correctly (e.g. if you have a file named `project.py` and you try to access its function `get_token()` you can access it for testing as follows:

   ```
   import project

   def test_get_token():
       assert project.get_token() == whatever you are expecting to be returned
   ```
3. If the second step is being done correctly check that the spelling of your functions in your test file matches that of the functions in the original file.